# error in sql from php

Tags: php, mysql

i am not seeing it... When i echo the output everything is shown correct. But when i write it to the database i get an error...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO features (titel_alias, titel, platform, uitgever, ontwikkelaar, engine, gamesoort, genre, multiplayer, coop, spelers, speelduur, release, metacritic, leeftijd) VALUES ('$titel_alias', '$titel', '$platform', '$uitgever', '$ontwikkelaar', '$engine', '$gamesoort', '$genre', '$multiplayer', '$coop', '$spelers', '$speelduur', '$release', '$metacritic', '$leeftijd')") or die("Error:  ".mysql_error());
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release,
>   metacritic, leeftijd) VALUES

And it tells me this over and over at the release part

The echo below works... i am really not seeing it...

```
echo $titel . "<br/>";
echo $titel_alias . "<br/>";
echo $ontwikkelaar . "<br/>";
echo $uitgever . "<br/>";
echo $engine . "<br/>";
echo $platform . "<br/>";
echo $gamesoort . "<br/>";
echo $genre . "<br/>";
echo $multiplayer . "<br/>";
echo $coop . "<br/>";
echo $spelers . "<br/>";
echo $speelduur . "<br/>";
echo $leeftijd . "<br/>";
echo $metacritic . "<br/>";
echo $release . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`release` is a MYSQL reserved word.

Wrap it in backticks.

```
`release`
```

See more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Comment: thanks that realy helped